# How to compare two arrays and then execute next statement just once?

Tags: c

I have pseudo code which is as follows

```
unsigned int array_1[20] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1};
unsigned int array_2[20] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1};

if (array_1 != array_2)   
    printf("array is dissimilar"); // that statement should be executed just once
```

How I can implement that in C code?

Comment: [memcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp)

Comment: may i know the details how we can use that?

Comment: Did you read the manual? Or do a search for examples? `if (memcmp(array_1, array_2, sizeof(array_1)) != 0) printf("array is dissimilar");`

Comment: sure thanks it works

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

//equal method compares if two array are equal or not
int equal(int *arr1, int *arr2, int size1, int size2){
    //check the size of the two array's 
    if(size1 != size2) return 0;
    for(int i=0;i < size1;i++)
        if(arr1[i] != arr2[i])
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    int arr1[5]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, arr2[5]={1, 2, 3, 5, 4};
    //for (int i=0;i<sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(int);i++)
    //  printf("%d ",  arr2[i]);
    if (!equal(arr1, arr2, sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(int), sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(int)))
        printf("Unequal\n");

    return 0;
}
```

### Output :

```
$ gcc array_compare.c && ./a.out
Unequal
```

Comment: It might be neater to do `if (size1 != size2) return 0;` which saves a level of indentation.  I think you should use a bit more space in your code, too; blank lines between functions, and spacing after commas (but not between the `*` and variable name in `int *arr`!), and within expressions generally.

Comment: thanks for the answer. here why we are checking size of arrays? we are sure size is always same just wana check if contents are same or different, if it is different just print out ones indicating arrays are different.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. My issue has been solved